# Citing papers in Statement of purpose

Tags: graduate-admissions, citations, undergraduate, statement-of-purpose, citation-style

I am citing papers in Statement of Purpose.

I am only using - "**first author et al**". instead of the recommend cite as per the paper's norms.

Would that be okay or should I just use the normal reference which goes into writing papers?

Comment: _recommend[ed] cite as per the paper's norms_: Where is that recommended?

Comment: Normally while citing a paper (as per IEEE conference) 6 names should be mentioned before using "et al." or all the equal contributors. In that sense!

Comment: You'll likely find that rules from different venues conflict. E.g., I've seen et al. for just three authors.

Comment: That's true, it's quite rarely less than 3 in my field hence I asked the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Statement of Purpose is self-contained (in particular, it includes a list of references), you're free to pick your own citation format. Otherwise, you need to pick a format that allows the reader to identify the work you're citing. Using *first author et al.* probably doesn't help, because that author will likely have written many papers, moreover, their name is not likely unique. Using

> *author et al. (venue, year)*

should suffice.

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful!